# In a class extended PagerAdapter, how to ensure instantiateItem run after constructor

Tags: java, android, async-await

In a class extended from PagerAdapter, how to ensure instantiateItem run after constructor.If not, how to deliver a list from constructor into  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position ) {}